# ios 8+ and ios 7 [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName Differences crash my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` to send a Notification to all classes listened to

In this way:

```
#define kReceiveCMD @"RECEIVE_CMD"
```

I send it to:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: kReceiveCMD object: cmd userInfo: nil];
```

I signed up for listening:

```
 - (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {

        [super viewWillAppear: animated];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector:selector (receiveCMD :) name: kReceiveCMD object: nil];
    }
```

Class were listening - is going to function (`ReceiveCMD :`) gets the object (cmd) successfully

```
-(void) receiveCMD:(NSNotification *)obj{
    ServerCommand* cmd = [obj object];

   if (cmd->CommandNo == [CMDVB_ServerIdle commandConst]) {

        NSLog(@"ServerIdle");

        return;


    }

}
```

Finally when coming to the end of the function, - application crashes

[Xcode show it this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qGML.png)

The error message:

> - [__ NSCFString errorInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f1bbb0 2015-12-01 12: 17: 44.659 HOMismart [403: 60b] ***
>     Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '- [__ NSCFString errorInfo:]:
>     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f1bbb0'
>     *** First throw call stack: (0x2d5e8f83 0x37d99ccf 0x2d5ec917 0x2d5eb203 0x2d53a768 0x2d5ab1a1 0x2d51f4ef 0x2df0aa3d 0x262a7d
>     0x2d5ab1a1 0x2d51f4ef 0x2df0aa3d 0x2df0f31b 0x21e435 0xf3239 0xf2d33
>     0x21dad7 0xdaa5b 0x1e6617 0x38281833 0x3828181f 0x38281777 0x2d5b38a1
>     0x2d5b2175 0x2d51cebf 0x2d51cca3 0x32422663 0x2fe6914d 0x153689
>     0x382a6ab7) libc ++ abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>     type NSException

This problem only occurs iPhone 4 / 4S running on Ios7, in Ios8 + everything is working properly

Comment: Please add the code for receiveCMD :

Comment: You define key for notification, but use different one. It it typo in question?

Comment: shai - i׳v now add it

Comment: raker - sorry it change it now from ReceiveCMD to kReceiveCMD

Comment: Why are you using this syntax: `cmd->CommandNo`?  You probably have a memory management bug, and you are just lucky when it works.

Comment: its happen even if receiveCMD is empty , and in ios 8/9 its works perfectly

Comment: You are not using proper ObjC syntax. You should read some introduction to ObjC.

Comment: Why in code we see RECEIVE_CMD like variable, and in code snippets like #define?